# ARKit Changing X and Z axis

Tags: arkit

I made an OpenVR Driver for ARKit but ARKit changes my X and Z axis when i change Yaw axis. I tried changing axis for all possibilities for yaw axis(180-90, 90-0, 0-(-90),-90-(-180) but when i did this all old position changing. Can anyone help me about algorithm.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide the details on what have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you! I tried change X and Z axis but when i did this my old position data is changing too and i tried calculate axis from position changing but I was not able to write the algorithm.